# Difference between Template Driven Form and Reactive Form using a service

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-forms

I would like to know when should I use a template driven form instead of a Reactive form. I know the theory based in that question([What are the practical differences between template-driven and reactive forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142616/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-template-driven-and-reactive-forms)) but I don't know which one use with Angular Material. I always have doubts about which use.

Could anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an Angular focused developer I recommend always using reactive form setups.

Developers will argue but trust me you will be saving yourself headaches later. Netanel B wrote about it here too: [Why It’s Time to Say Goodbye to Angular Template-Driven Forms](https://netbasal.com/why-its-time-to-say-goodbye-to-angular-template-driven-forms-350c11d004b)

Let's say you want a very simple input, you may be tempted to simply use

- ngModel
- template variables
- @ViewChild

They may be fine, for now.

But let's say you need to add:

- Validation
- Watching for changes
- Updating the value programmatically

These all require you rely on and code around the method you've chosen to access the input.

Where [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) are a pre-built API which brings a standard to each need.

Answer (score 2):

**Template-driven forms**

- Use template-driven forms when developing static forms. Static means the structure and logic of a form is fix. E.g. the number of form fields does not vary, form validation rules are the same for different user roles, etc.
- Examples are login forms, reset password forms, forms to enter and edit address data, order data and similar fix data structures.

**Reactive-forms**

- Use the reactive forms approach in case the form shall support dynamic data structures and logic. Examples are dynamic survey forms, forms to add/delete 0..n tags or phone numbers, forms providing different validation for different user roles, etc.
- The structure and logic of reactive forms is mainly implemented in TypeScript. Corresponding HTML artifacts only refer to the form controls defined in TypeScript. At highest expansion stage a reactive form can be entirely generated at runtime based on a data structure.

For more detail you can refer the follow this [link](https://medium.com/@steffen.klepke/angular-template-driven-forms-and-reactive-forms-in-a-nutshell-f09f3b2fb2dc)